# Parallel Programs for GPU

Tags: software, google, us20140180989

[US 2014/0180989 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140180989) has been applied by Google. It seems that the patent is about [convolutional neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) with parallel architecture. I have searched further and found that several companies including Microsoft have applied for a [similar patents](https://www.google.com/patents/US7747070). Neurala, LLC already has a [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US8648867), which seems to cover a broad range of computer programs utilizing GPU.

On the other hand, nVidia, a major GPU maker, provides [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone) technology as a tool for developing GPU-based programs and seems to be encouraging the development. They also provide a large [list of such applications](http://www.nvidia.com/content/gpu-applications/PDF/GPU-apps-catalog-mar2015.pdf).

It seems that use of GPU as a parallel platform is expanding but nobody is worried about patent infringement.
I don’t understand what’s going on. Do we really have to worry about anything about patent at all when we develop a parallel program for GPU with CUDA, which is readily provided for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The mere fact that nVidia provides CUDA for developing GPU-based programs does not absolve others (like yourself) of any potential patent infringement. If you make, sell, use, import, etc., something that includes all the elements of one of the claims of an issued patent, you are infringing that patent.

Many tech companies do build large patent portfolios to be used defensively--that is, they do not plan to sue others for patent infringement, but if they are sued, they have plenty of ammunition for a countersuit. But you cannot count on a patent holder to ignore your infringement.